# Issue using AsyncStorage to persist login in React Native with a Rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-native, authentication, expo, asyncstorage

I am trying to persist a login using AsyncStorage for a React Native app with a Rails backend. I can't figure out how to implement it correctly. My setUser function works correctly to setState but I am then trying to use AsyncStorage to store the userId from the login. Then when the component mounts after reopening the app I would like to be able to get userId from AsyncStorage to use in the auto_login fetch.

```
    const user_id = AsyncStorage.getItem("userId")
    if(user_id) {
      fetch("http://localhost:3000/auto_login", {
        headers: {
          "Authorization": user_id
        }
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        if (res.errors){
          alert(res.errors)
        } else {
          this.setState({ currentUser: res, loggedIn: true})
        }
      })
    }

    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/users`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(users => this.setState({ users: users }))

    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/tasks`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(tasks => this.setState({ tasks: tasks }))
  }

  setUser = (user) => {
    this.setState({
      currentUser: user,
      loggedIn: true
    }, () => {
      AsyncStorage.setItem("userId", user.id)
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

AsyncStorage is asychronous. You need to add `await`:

```
const user_id = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userId")
```